# In Python 3.6, how can I convert an unknown string to a set?

Tags: python, input, set

I want the program to read an input. Unless the input is "HELP", it consists of several integers separated by spaces. I don't know the number of integers provided.

I want the integers to be placed in a set.

This is the code I am currently using, but it takes a long time and I am looking for a faster method.

```
nextInput = input()
while nextInput != "HELP":
    testString = set()
    testString1 = nextInput.split()
    for j in range(0, len(testString1)):
        k = int(testString1[j])
        testString.add(k)
    nextInput = input()
```

Comment: `nextInput` never changes inside the loop, so this loop never ends.

Comment: There are more things happening inside the loop, but they involve multiple other variables. Would it be helpful for me to post the rest of the code here?

Comment: You need to post a minimal amount of code, but it should still be representative. I would say the loop is not relevant to your problem, so remove the loop part.

Comment: I just edited the question to add another input line to get out of the loop. The loop is how I am getting the first input into the set. My question is whether there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that set() accepts an iterable as parameter, so you can replace the whole body of your while with

```
testString = set(nextInput.split())
```

**Edit:** If you need to have a set of numbers (which wasn't clear in the original question, specially as the variable name was "testString"; I will change the name of the variable for my own sanity) replace that line with

```
numset = set(int(_) for _ in nexInput.split())
```

Below that, of course, you should add the line to ask for the next input.

Of course, if you want to be fully pythonic you would ask the input only once, you would do:

```
while True:
  nextInput = input()
  if nextInput == 'HELP':
    break
  numset = set(int(_) for _ in nexInput.split())
```

Comment: @user8920020 Yep this is the idea, but it won't accept updates and the items are still strings

Comment: I just noticed that you also needed to update the existing set. In that case, the answer from Anton VBR is better, even if he uses a map instead of a generator expresion.

Comment: Don't worry! There are tons of problems out there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Create empty set
testString = set()

while True:

    # Ask for input
    nextInput = input()

    # Break if user writes help
    if nextInput.upper() == 'HELP':
        break

    # Try to update the set with ints else print Error!
    try: 
        testString.update(map(int,nextInput.split()))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error with input!")
```